# Ругается на System.out.println в импортированном классе

Tags: java, импорт, java.lang.system

Есть 2 класса: `DogTestDrive` и `Dog`. Класс `Dog` лежит в папке `pets`.

`DogTestDrive`:

```
import pets.Dog;

public class DogTestDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Dog d = new Dog();
       System.out.println(d.name);
    }
}
```

`Dog`:

```
public class Dog
{   
    public String name = "Шарик";
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Компилирую через командную строку — ругается на `System.out.println` в классе `Dog`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю, почему? Если закоментировать эту строку вывода в классе `Dog` — все работает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому, что вызов  `System.out.println(name);` внутри класса Dog не должен происходить вне какого-либо метода.

Можно сделать вот так, например:

```
public class Dog {   
    public String name = "Шарик";

    public Dog() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Таким образом, вызов будет делаться из конструктора, при создании объекта.

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало. А можно ссылку об этом почитать хочется подробнее понять почему так

Comment: Да что тут читать. System.out это просто объект класса PrintStream. А работа с объектами одного класса, внутри другого класса, выполняется только в методах. Это может быть блок static, конструктор или функция. Изучайте дальше, позже вы со всем ознакомитесь подробнее.